# Open a new window using data from input form

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, jquery-events

In a input form in a HTML file, the user is supposed to put an URL (let's call it `thislink`). Then I want, when the user clicks on the submit button, to open a new window whose URL integrates `thislink`, that is its URL should be: `'/selection/yes/?value='+thislink'`.

Here are 2 tentatives of code:

1st tentative:

```
<form id="urlarticle">
  <input type='text' name='thislink'>
  <input type='submit' value='Select' onclick = function() {window.open('/selection/yes/?value='+thislink)};>
</form>
```

2nd tentative:

```
<form id="urlarticle">
  <input type='text' name='thislink'>
  <input type='submit' value='Select'>
</form>

<script type='application/javascript'>
    $("#urlarticle").submit(function() {
        window.open('/selection/yes/?value='+thislink);
    });     
</script>
```

But both tentatives are not working, any help to get the right way to write it appreciated!

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: read the input's value

Comment: (1) use `id` instead of `name`. (2) `$("#thislink").val();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you tagged jQuery, you could do it like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/729uh/

Javascript:

```
$("#urlarticle").submit(function() {
    var linkValue = $('input[name="thislink"]').val();
    window.open('/selection/yes/?value='+linkValue);
});
```

Html:

```
<form id="urlarticle">
    <input type='text' name='thislink'/>
    <input type='submit' value='Select'/>
</form>
```

What this does is:

- use jQuery to select the `input` that has a `name` attribute with value `thislink`
- take the value that was written in it
- append that value to your link